# Is there currently support for text to text transformers in ML.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I want to create a model for translation, basically input a string of a certain length in one language (like Japanese) and output a string of similar length in another language (like English).

Because I'm not a fan of Python (which most ML uses for some reason) I'm currently looking into ML.Net for this, but as far as I can tell there is no algorithm that supports this kind of data mapping. The closest I found was categorizing (basically string to enum), but that doesn't work as there are virtually infinite categorize.

I'm just really puzzled by this as translation, or chat bots, are quit old usecases for ML. I searched the web, but I still think I'm missing something here.